# Xcode 9 beta 3 - Swift 3.2: comparing optional

Tags: xcode9-beta, swift3.2

Project which compiles fine in Xcode 8.3.2 shows many compilation errors around comparing optional/non optional value with ==

What I have found is an older proposal for removing coparison <> for the same:
https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0121-remove-optional-comparison-operators.md

So now in Xcode 9, I can not even compare two optionals:

```
    let xxx: String? =  "A"
    let yyy: String? = "B"

    if xxx == yyy { //ERROR: Ambiguous use of operator '=='

    }
```

Could someone point me to a resource where this would be explained? 
Or is it just a temporary bug?

Thanks

Comment: It's building fine with swift 4, and swift 3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XCode 9 beta (9M136h) and  Swift 4, your instruction compiles.

Variants of **==** and **!=** which accept optional operands are still useful, and their results unsurprising, so **they will remain**.

Remove the versions of <, <=, >, and >= which accept optional operands.

So your instruction should works either in Swift 3.2 or Swift 4. 
Check the swift version you are using in the build settings -> Swift Language Version.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. There was a hidden extension overriding operator == for some type of objects. The fact is, Xcode 8 compiled the code fine, while Xcode 9 Swift 3.2 was confused.